# Suma valores de dos campos Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas de las cuales una es para el registro de los productos y sus valores, y la otra del carrito. Para tomar los valores de compra de los productos, están haciendo lo siguiente:

```
SELECT (PROD.product_price * CART.cart_amount) AS ValorTotal FROM pd_cart CART
INNER JOIN pd_products PROD
        ON CART.cart_id_product = PROD.product_id
     WHERE CART.cart_token = 'ABBEAD63DEE08DA1EEFE753524E65F9AE81435AB369D66D37CE6F9F31255896108B2ED481D54C50DBC972D5678D60744789FE264213F0F8B7F905276D9B51647'
       AND CART.cart_status = 'A';
```

Con esta consulta, tengo el siguiente resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora necesito sumar los valores de la Valor_Total. Entiendo que SUM() hace la suma, pero ¿cómo puedo aplicar en esta consulta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduciendo la consulta que acabas de definir como una subconsulta de una consulta de totales que realice la suma que buscas:

```
SELECT SUM(ValorTotal) FROM (
    SELECT (PROD.product_price * CART.cart_amount) AS ValorTotal
      FROM pd_cart CART
      INNER JOIN pd_products PROD ON CART.cart_id_product = PROD.product_id
      WHERE CART.cart_token = 'ABBEAD63DEE08DA1EEFE753524E65F9AE81435AB369D66D37CE6F9F31255896108B2ED481D54C50DBC972D5678D60744789FE264213F0F8B7F905276D9B51647'
      AND CART.cart_status = 'A'  
  ) c1;
```

O realizando la suma directamente, puesto que tu consulta aún puede convertirse en una consulta de totales:

```
SELECT SUM(PROD.product_price * CART.cart_amount) AS ValorTotal
  FROM pd_cart CART
  INNER JOIN pd_products PROD ON CART.cart_id_product = PROD.product_id
  WHERE CART.cart_token = 'ABBEAD63DEE08DA1EEFE753524E65F9AE81435AB369D66D37CE6F9F31255896108B2ED481D54C50DBC972D5678D60744789FE264213F0F8B7F905276D9B51647'
  AND CART.cart_status = 'A';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, David. Ambos trabajaron.